# Binding <KEY> Entrys to functions, then running the them with no button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, binding, key

So im trying to make a calculator for a game. Im having issues binding entry's to a function and then that function using the "input" to do its calculation and then print it.

The below functions are inputs needed from the user to do the calculations:

```
from tkinter import *

def refineRate(event):

    if refineRate == int():
        refineRate = int(refineRate)
        return refineRate
    else:
        refineRate = float(refineRate)
        return refineRate

def veldCalc(event):

    minValue = open("mineral_value.csv", "r")
    veld = minValue.readlines()[0]
    minValue.close()
    veld = veld[0:3]
    veld = int(veld)
    veld = veld / 100 * refineRate(event)
    refinedVeld = veld * veldCalc(event)
    print (refinedVeld)
```

Then i have the GUI aspect where i have the labels and entrys for the user to input this data. I would like it to work using the `<KEY>` binding so it updates live.

The idea is the user inputs there refine rate which should then return that data in the `refineRate` function then input the Quanity of materials they have which should then use that data to run the calc in the `veldCalc` function

Once these functions are complet the result is printed out.

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Ore Calculator")
root.geometry("600x600")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

repro = Label(root, text="Reprocessing %")
repro_entry = Entry(root)
repro.grid(row=0, column=0)
repro_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)


veld = Label(root, text="Veldspar: ")
veld_entry = Entry(root)
veld.grid(row=1, column=0)
veld_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

repro_entry.bind("<KEY>", refineRate)
veld_entry.bind("<KEY>", veldCalc)


root.mainloop()
```

ATM im getting the following errors:

```
line 40, in <module>
    repro_entry.bind("<KEY>", refineRate)

line 1245, in bind
    return self._bind(('bind', self._w), sequence, func, add)

line 1200, in _bind
    self.tk.call(what + (sequence, cmd))

_tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "KEY"
```

im not sure what i am missing, i have read other post about this but all seems to be using buttons and rather then any key commands. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try binding to `<KeyPress>`.

Comment: Events are case sensitive.

Comment: The command <KEY> should be caps according to python guides and everything think else match's ?

Comment: but that worked thanks :)